# C# webbrower automatically clicking a menu button

Tags: c#, click

I have seen a few of these questions on here but, none of them answered my question. I am looking to automatically click a button on the google fusion table page. I want to run this is in a windows form in visual studio 2015. I need to navigate to the file-geocode... button. I right clicked and hit the inspect button and this is the ID for the button I want

`<td class="gwt-MenuItem" id="gwt-uid-209" role="menuitem" colspan="2">Geocode...</td>`

is it possible to use a method similar to this?:

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document
            .GetElementById("gwt-uid-209")
            .InvokeMember("Click");
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i used the same code that you mentioned in the question but be careful because the webBrowser may invoke more than 1 events while the document is completing.

i usually set a timer with 1000ms interval;
try this, it will take 1 second more but it will do the job.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      timer1.Enabled = false;
      webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gwt-uid-209").InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Comment: consider using GeckoFX that use mozilla instead of internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the geckobrowser how do I get it to autoclick? this is what I have now.

```
Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
            var geckoWebBrowser = new GeckoWebBrowser { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            Form f = new Form();
            f.Controls.Add(geckoWebBrowser);
            geckoWebBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1FdRUOJ9YIXT81QdfS71qXWV3m7qmzF_4TLRrKh5r#rows:id=1");
            Application.Run(f);
```